# Android activity difference between active and running

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I was reading the Android documentation on the Android developer [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and I read the following near the Android Activity Lifecycle:

```
If an activity in the foreground of the screen (at the top of the stack), it is active or running.
```

What is the difference between active and running? It says that they are both on the foreground of the screen, so I can't see the real difference between those states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An activity can still be *running*, but it is not *active*, whenever it is still visible on the screen, but partially obscured by another activity.